# Android table layout adapter suggestions?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-adapter, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to create an app that will help keep track of attendance information for team meetings and events. It is a simple app that will display a sort of spreadsheet style look. The rows are each person on the team and the columns are dates when events and meetings happen.

I'm doing this with an SQL database, and I am going to be dynamically adding rows and columns to the database.

The question I have is this... Is there a good layout / adapter combo to use to make it easier to pull the data from the database and put it into the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so... at least there isn't say for example, a TableAdapter that automatically formats a TableLayout with the correct columns.

Since you are pulling information from a database, I'm not sure I would recommend a TableLayout at all, but more a ListView, *possibly* with a single row TableLayout for the item views, though a linear layout would probably suffice.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that as a fall back if there was no sort of "TableAdapter" type thing. Just a ListView of horizontal linear layouts.